# Adding mouse listener to java swt image

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swt, listener

Okay so i have image created like this:

```
Image deleteImage = new Image(viewer.getTable().getDisplay(),
                        Provider.PATH_TO_DELETE_ICON);
```

How do i add mouse listener so i know when the image is clicked?

Here is my label provider class:

```
private class MyLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements
            ITableLabelProvider {

        @Override
        public Image getColumnImage(Object element, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 3) {
                Image deleteImage = new Image(viewer.getTable().getDisplay(),
                        Provider.PATH_TO_DELETE_ICON);
                return deleteImage;
            }
            if (columnIndex == 4) {
                Image editImage = new Image(viewer.getTable().getDisplay(),
                        Provider.PATH_TO_EDIT_ICON);
                return editImage;
            } else
                return null;
        }

        public String getColumnText(Object element, int index) {
            Provider provider = (Provider) element;
            switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return Integer.toString(provider.getId());
            case 1:
                return provider.getName();
            case 2:
                return provider.getBulstat();
            default:
                return "";
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `Label`, set you image onto it via

```
label.setImage(deleteImage)
```

Afterwards you can do the following:

```
label.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Click");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: That would be the solution but it needs to be an image because i am getting it from the LabelProvider of the viewer. If you can tell me how can a LabelProvider's getImage method return a Button instead of an image that would be the solution.

Comment: Create your own `LabelProvider` and override the `getImage()` method? Just a guess, haven't used `LabelProvider` yet. Just realized, you cannot override a method, if you change the return type... Then I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The LabelProvider is used in a TableViewer, right? Can't you add a Listener to that one instead? Which LabelProvider do you use?

Comment: I can but the source of the mouse event becomes the Table of the TableViewer... I need the source to be the Image object.

Comment: Ok, what if you implement `MouseListener` in your `LabelProvider`? Would that work? Sorry, I'm a bit lost here...

Comment: It won't dude.. Because when a mouse event is fired the source object of the event is the whole Table not the Image in the cell which i want to be the source of the event.

Comment: But you could use the `x` and `y` coordinates of the event to find the Image.

Comment: This will not work because i am building an eclipse rcp application and the x and y coordinate of the image will be different compared to those of the event object because the Image object is in different Shell. I tested it.

Comment: I had a related issue with RCP once, have you tried to call `table.toControl(event.x, event.y)`? It should transform the coordinates to the correct ones. Worked for me.